# Changing items while running

Tags: python, dynamic, gtk, pygtk

I'm creating a indicator applet using Python (pygtk) and I have a function that looks for a process. I need the item in the menu to be able to change while still running the script.

The item in the menu should kill or start a process, based on if it's running or not.

Also, I want a text-only item to change while running, but this one should continually change to show the latest row from a text file.

How do I update the items in the code without restarting the script?

See code here: https://github.com/danielholm/BareShare/blob/master/bareshare.py

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now.

You can use set_label() anytime, and since GTK main keeps looping over and over, you can use a code to update the label at a set time:

```
gobject.timeout_add(1000, self.funcion, None)

def function(self, widget)
  self.label.set_label(uploadM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for the `set_label` method of `gtk.MenuItem`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html#method-gtkmenuitem--set-label).

In order to make the item not clickable, you want to to use `set_sensitive` method of `gtk.Widget` to make the widget insensitive. See the documentation for that [here](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-sensitive).

You can also use the `get_label` method of `gtk.MenuItem` to retrieve whatever text you've stored in the `gtk.MenuItem`.

An example would be:

```
my_menu_item = gtk.MenuItem("Script is runnning")
my_menu_item.set_sensitive(False)
```

And then later, when the state of the script changes:

```
my_menu_item.set_text("Script is not running")
```

Comment: Well, yes, among other things. Though I dont want it to be clickable.

So label will be able to change while running the script?

Comment: You mean first use set_label and then get_label just like get_active?

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying this out on row 219 and 223. Is that correct?